# Magento 1.9 Support stop will affect the current site. Did authorize.net also stop support?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2.3, theme, payment-methods, authorize.net

I planning to upgrade the Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.3 in mid of June. meanwhile, what is an issue that occurred on Magento 1.9? Also, authorize.net will stop accept the payment in Magento 1.9. What happens if I could not find the theme after upgrade the Magento.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I highly appreciated that you are planning to migrate your store from M1 to M2 as I've seen very few people are working on that.

All the M1 stores will be up and running but the major issue is security as been said Magento won't provide any security patches. So it might also affect PCI compliance. However, there're companies that are helping with the extended security for Magento 1 store. You can also check'em out.